# how to calculate survival time and Event

Tags: survival, rare-events

If I have 10 wild type flies in a bottle and I study them for 13 days to see how many survive or die or are lost. Similarly i have 10 mutant flies in a jar and I observe the following die or are lost over a period of 13 days.

How can i Compute the survival time and event for 10 wild type flies and 10 mutant flies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why you cannot fill those question marks?  Such as for worm 1 do you have information that when this guy  was dead?  If it was dead at day 3 then the survival time will be 3 days and the events will be 1. Suppose you will observe all flies to die then there will no censored data.  If you only observe 12 days, then for flies that lived more than 12 days their survival days will be 12 (in fact will be 12+) and the event will be 0 (censored). For lost flies, the survival time will be the days when you did  the last observation and they were also censored event =0.

Comment: Also you can search Kaplan-Meier or product-limit method to see how to assign the survival time and events and how to calculate the survival probabilities.

Comment: @DeepNorth thank you for your help, I'll look into Kaplan-Meier and product-limit methods